# How do I view a session variable using Flask/Jinja2?

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy

Can anyone tell me how I can view a session variable within flask, so that I can retreive the current logged in user?  With my 'for loop' I can view all items iterated, but I need the current logged in user...

Thanks in advance

app.py

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///dude.db', echo=True)
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    if session.get('logged_in'):
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        s = Session()
        user = s.query(User.username)
        for i in user:
            print i
        return render_template('index.html', user = user)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: If you'd use flask-login, you'd be able to [access the current user in templates through `current_user` proxy](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#login-example). Also since you're already in the flask ecosystem, why not use [flask-sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing these two things:

- the [**Flask session object**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#sessions)
- a **database session in SQLAlchemy** *(e.g. [sessionmaker](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#session-and-sessionmaker) is a SQLAlchemy thing).*

The general pattern for a Flask session (e.g. signed crypto cookie using your secret key, you must have the `secret_key` configuration set to use these) is like this:

```
from flask import session, redirect, url_for, render_template


@app.route('/login/')
def login():
    # logic to sign in user
    # then set session variable
    session['profile'] = {"user_id": 5, "user_name": "Tom"}

    return redirect(url_for('main'))


@app.route('/logout/')
def logout():
    # logic to sign out user
    # clear session
    session.clear()

    return redirect(url_for('main'))


@app.route('/')
def main():
    user = None
    if 'profile' in session:
        user = session['profile']
    return render_template('index.html', user=user)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have put a lot of time into it and still trying to learn.  All I'm wanting to do is extract the current user name so I can display it.  Shouldn't be that difficult.